# How do you access cookies "expires" value in Rails 4 tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 2.3 tests you could access the expiration time of a cookie like this:

```
cookies[:something].expires
```

But I can't figure out how to access this with Rails 4 since `cookies[:something]` just returns the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one solution, but there **HAS** to be a better way:

```
cookies.instance_eval('@set_cookies')['something'][:expires]
```

Answer (score -1):

The Rails 4 way:

```
cookies[:something][:expires]
```

Comment: That doesn't work in rails 4.  cookies[:something] returns a string, not a hash?